# kubernetes-how to subdomain localhost using nginx ingress controller?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, nginx-ingress

I want to have 2 apps running on kubernetes, I wonder if I can do 2 subdomains using nginx ingress controller.

For example: `app1.localhost:8181/cxf` and `app2.localhost:8181/cxf`
each one of those will have diferent services.

How can I do that?

Some more context here:

EDIT:

Note:mysql is working fine so im not posting the yaml's here so it doesn't get too long.

Note too that im using karaf with a kar.(that will be my app)

I was thinking that maybe I should have 2 nodes? one with mysql and app1 and the other one with mysql and app2? so in one I could access `app1.localhost/cxf` services and in the other `app2.localhost/cxf` services... maybe doesn't make much sense... and I was reading that I need kubeadm for that, and there is no way to install it on windows. I think I must use minikube for that instead?

These are my yaml's:

**The load balancer:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: lb-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: app1
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: app1
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  - protocol: TCP
    name: app1-8080
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  - protocol: TCP
    name: app1-8101
    port: 8101
    targetPort: 8101
  - protocol: TCP
    name: app1-8181
    port: 8181
    targetPort: 8181
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - hostname: localhost
```

**app1:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8101
  selector:
    app: app1
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app1
        image: app1:latest
```

**app2:** is the same as app1 but in a diferent version(older services)

**ingress-resource:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apps-ingress
  #annotations:
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.localhost # tried app1.127-0-0-1.sslip.io ass answered below too.
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app1-service
          servicePort: 8181
  - host: app2.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app2-service
          servicePort: 8181
```

I should be able to access app1 version in `app1.localhost:8181/cxf`, and app2 version in `app2.localhost:8181/cxf`

There is another doubt I have, shouldn't I be able to create another loadBalancer? I wanted to, so the selector would be app2 in that loadBalancer, but since I already have one, the new one just stays `<pending>` until I remove the first one.

That would make some sense, since if I have 2 replicas if app1, and 2 replicas of app2, there should be a loadBalancer for each app right?

Note that I installed the nginx ingress-controller using helm too, since the ingress-resource would not work otherwise, at least thats what I have read.

By installing that, it installed nginx load balancer too, and this one didnt go to pending. Do I need to use nginx loadBalancer? or can I delete it and use kubernetes type loadBalancer?

Huum, im missing something here...

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to have 2 apps running on kubernetes, I wonder if I can do 2 subdomains using nginx ingress controller.

Yes, you just need any number of DNS records which point to your Ingress controller's IP (you used 127.0.0.1, so that's what I'll use for these examples, but you can substitute whatever IP is relevant). That's the whole point of an Ingress resource: to use the `host:` header to dispatch requests into the cluster

I found [a list of wildcard DNS providers](https://moss.sh/free-wildcard-dns-services/) of which I confirmed that `app1.127-0-0-1.sslip.io` and `app2.127-0-0-1.sslip.io` do as expected

Thus:

```yaml
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1-and-2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.127-0-0-1.sslip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app1-backend
          servicePort: 8181  # <-- or whatever your Service port is

  # then you can repeat that for as many hosts as you wish
  - host: app2.127-0-0-1.sslip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app2-backend
          servicePort: 8181
```

Comment: It seems to work, thank you. I actually only had to change the host to app1.127-0-0-1.sslip.io.

After this some questions emerged:
1-Why didn't it work with app1.localhost:8181/cxf ? It's because I need to use a free DNS provider? but I was just testing in my local, so I thought it should work too...
2-My app uses 2 ports, 8181 and 8080, even so that I created an external load balancer exposing the ports using a selector, the services in 8080 didn't work. shouldn't that be enough? or I must add the port too somehow in the Ingress?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: edit: when I mean I have an external loadBalancer, its actually just a service with type LoadBalancer.

Im not using any cloud provider. maybe thats the problem?

Comment: nevermind about the port question. its actually working! my bad...
Thank you very much.
But please, if u can answer me the first question.... thx!

Comment: btw, shouldn't I be able to connect using ssh to each app1.127-0-0-1.sslip.io and app2.127-0-0-1.sslip.io?

Comment: edit: after some test I realize its not actually workin... I have app1 in app1.127-0-0-1.sslip.io and app2 in app2.127-0-0-1.sslip.io

and it calls app1  always, not app2...

i will edit my post and add more info soon

Comment: edit 2- its actually doing load balacing between the 2 services... what I want is to allways call app2 in app2.127-0-0-1.sslip.io, I just have 1 pod there, but if I scale to 2 it should then use load balancer to change between pod1 and pod2 in app2.127-0-0-1.sslip.io...